# how to change json schema in spark spark streamning events without interrupting the streamning Job?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a use case in which I need to change the schema of JSON without interrupting the streaming job. I am using a conf file where I have all the required schema mentioned. I have already tried cache and broadcast variables by persisting and unpersisting with a separate streaming pipeline but still no luck. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

rather than reading the data set as json you can try reading it as text and then map it as per a schema that that coming externally from a config file in HDFS or a DB.

so instead of doing something like,

```
val df = spark.readStream.format("json").load(.. path ..)
```

do,

```
import sparkSession.implicits._

val df = spark.readStream
.format("text").load( .. path .. )
.select("value")
.as[String]
.mapPartitions(partStrings => {
    val currentSchema = readSchemaFromFile(???)
    partStrings.map(str => parseJSON(currentSchema, str))
})
```

`mapPartitions` prevents schema lookup on each record.